# How to accept and pass two parameter as props

Tags: reactjs

Hi I need to pass two parameters, to the class Chat. Currently it is getting only one parameter and displaying correctly.

```
const Chat = props => (
    <div >
        <ul>{props.messages.map(message => <li key={message}>{message}</li>)}</ul>

    </div>
);
```

This Chat.js file is called from the Home.js. Suppose I need to pass the Chat component two parameters and I tried it like following.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { User } from './User';
import  Chat  from './Chat';

export class Home extends Component {
    displayName = Home.name

    state = {
        messages: [],
        names: []
    };

    handleSubmit = (message,name) =>
        this.setState(currentState => ({
            messages: [...currentState.messages, message],
            names: [...currentState.names,name]

    }));

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <User onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Chat messages={this.state.messages,this.state.name} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In this scenario how should I change the Chat component to accept two parameters and display inside div tags.
This is what I tried. But seems it is incorrect.

```
const Chat = props => (
    <div >
        <ul>{props.messages.map((message, name) => <li key={message}>{message}</li> <li key={name}>{name}</li>)}</ul>

    </div>
);
```

PS: The User Method

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class User extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            message: ''

        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <div className="panel panel-default" id="frame1" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

            <form className="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php" >
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="control-label col-sm-2" htmlFor="name">Your Name </label>
                    <div className="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name"  onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="control-label col-sm-2" htmlFor="message">Message</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control"  name="message" placeholder="Enter your Message" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
       );
    }

    handleChange(evt) {
        this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSubmit(this.state.message, this.state.name);
        this.setState({ message: "" });
        this.setState({name:""});
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using separate attributes to pass different props. So for instance, you might revise your `<Home/>` components render method like so:

```
 <Chat messages={this.state.messages} names={this.state.names} />
```

and then to access these two bits of data (messages and name) from inside the `<Chat />` component you could do the following:

```
const Chat = props => (
    <div >
        <ul>{props.messages.map((message, index) => <li key={message}>
            From: { Array.isArray(props.names) ? props.names[index] : '-' } 
            Message: {message}</li>)}
        </ul>    
    </div>
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks . Unfortunately I still cant see the name. As you can see name is also an array. So I need to print it infront of messages inside the list. Like mentioning , the user who is sending the message

Comment: Still bad luck. Getting this error... Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference. Does this means no value is getting passed to Name

Comment: I updated my user method as well to check whether Im missing something

Comment: Yes it is exactly similar

Comment: Strange - just updated answer, what happens for you now?

Comment: Yes. it finally worked fine :) Thanks alot for you commitment. Im having a small question. Why can't we simply pass the name here instead of index as we did for messages

Comment: You're welcome glad I could help :-), that is because the `map()` function is called on the `messages` array which makes accessing each `message` trivial, where as to access a corresponding name requires using the index to fetch the name that corresponds to the current message

Comment: Got it. :) Thanks again for helping me out

Comment: You bet - all the best with your project :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass them separately:

```
<Chat messages={this.state.messages} name={this.state.name} />
```

Comment: Thanks. :) It worded fine